# How to dynamically assign data to an atomFamily with Recoil?

Tags: recoiljs

If I fetch dynamic data, how can I put it into an atomFamily without violating the rule of hooks? `useSetRecoilState` requires me to pass in `atomFamily(someIndex)`, but with dynamic data I don't have the `someIndex` until *after* fetching the data. So it seems like I should have `const setterFactory = someKey => useSetRecoilState(useAtomFamily(someKey))` but that violates the rule of hooks.

Example:

Assume I have an API response with accompanying type (and recoil atomFamily)

```js
type Foo = unknown & { index: string }
type Response = {
  foos: Foo[]
}
const myAtomFamily = useAtomFamily<Foo, string>({
  key: 'foo',
  default: null,
})
declare const fetchFromApi = () => Promise<Foo[]>
```

So if I have in a custom hook,

```js
const myHook = () => {
  const fooSetter = useSetRecoilState(myAtomFamily(???))

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchFromApi().then(foos => {
      foos.forEach(foo => fooSetter(???)(???))
    })
  }, [])
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can you use the `useRecoilCallback` hook for that, which is basically a factory hook that gives you access to the `set` function:

```js
const useMyHook = () => {
  const fetchAndSet = useRecoilCallback(({set}) => async () => {
    const foos = await fetchFromApi();

    foos.forEach(foo => set(myAtomFamily(foo.id), foo))
  }, [])

  useEffect(fetchAndSet, [])
}
```